# API calls not going to server when client is hosted MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, express, server, production, mern

I hosted my react application using surge.sh

https://deranged-ticket.surge.sh/

And my web server is running on my localhost:5000 , so when my frontend application makes api requests it goes to a diffrent url [as you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXc5h.png). How can i make it go to

https://localhost:5000/api/v1/transactions instead of 
https://deranged-ticket.surge.sh/api/v1/transactions

Comment: wait, you want your deployed client to hit _your_ localhost ? is this just for testing? or is your server deployed somewhere as well?

Comment: what are you using in React to send the request?

Comment: @azium yes it is for testing

Comment: @AbdullahAbid axios

Comment: you're probably using relative urls then right? `axios.get('/api')` use a full url if you want to change it to localhost

Comment: @azium yes exactly like that

Comment: So will it work if i give
axios.get('https://localhost:5000/api/v1/transactions') instead of relative routes ? let me check

Comment: it's better to write `axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/transactions') `  and to use a proxy so that by writing `/api` works as well

Comment: I changed all relative routes to ` axios.get('localhost:5000/api/v1/transactions')`  like this and published the changes and the api calls is still going to `https://deranged-ticket.surge.sh/api/v1/transactions`

Comment: did you forget the `http://` part before localhost?

Comment: @azium no , `axios.get("https://localhost:5000/api/v1/transactions");` this is my code

Comment: a fully qualified url won't go through your proxy.. however I think trying to get your deployed application to talk to your local server is very strange. why not deploy your server first and point it to there?

Comment: @azium i will work on that , thanks.

Comment: So how then after hosting my server somewhere should i use relative routes? and how will it work?

Comment: You can only use relative routes if your api is being served from the same domain as your client, or if you have a proxy setup to do that. you don't need a proxy though if you are also developing the server. either set it up on the same domain or configure cors correctly